# Cosa significa "sdrumarsi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto questo dialogo tra due partigiani che si sono appena trovati:

> – Non dirmi che ti ho messo paura, – disse Milton sedendoglisi accanto.
>    
>       – Ti giuro. Ormai sono debole di cuore. Questo mestiere per dar sul cuore è peggio del palombaro. Hai
>   spalancato l’uscio come una cannonata. E poi, sai che
>   faccia hai? Di’ un po’, è molto che non ti specchi?  
>       Milton **si sdrumò** la faccia con le mani. – Che stavate facendo? 
>        – Niente. Fino a cinque minuti fa abbiamo giocato alla mano del soldato. Da cinque minuti a questa parte sto
>   pensando.

Non capisco bene cosa vuol dire che "Milton si sdrumò la faccia". Ho letto la [definizione del verbo "sdrumare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sdrumare/), ma non sono sicura di aver colto il senso in questo contesto. 
Significa che Milton si picchiò violentemente la faccia con le mani?

Answer (score 4):

Credo voglia dire che si diede degli schiaffi sul viso. Subito dopo, si spiega che fino a cinque minuti prima stavano giocando alla mano del soldato, un gioco che si chiama anche schiaffo del soldato (https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiaffo_del_soldato). La mano può stare o dietro la schiena o accostata al viso.

Comment: Grazie, Benedetta! Infatti, volevo anche chiedere cosa significa "giocare alla mano del soldato", ma pensavo farlo in un'altra domanda. Tuttavia, non è Milton quello che stava facendo questo gioco, ma gli altri.

Comment: @Charo "Lo schiaffo del soldato” è un gioco molto antico: uno se ne sta rivolto al muro, tenendo una mano dietro la schiena, passandola davanti al petto e sotto al braccio; deve indovinare chi degli altri l'ha schiaffeggiato. Vedi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_SiK5LXvWQ

Answer (score 3):

Credo che sdrumare in questo contesto significhi semplicemente che se la massaggi, come quando ci si massaggia la faccia appena svegli dopo una notte passata male.

Per come ho sempre usato io il verbo, sdrumare ha un significato simile a "fare attrito", sfregare, possibilmente con forza. Accentuando questa accezione nasce poi il significato giovanile riportato nel dizionario: "sdrumare" la squadra avversaria non vuol dire picchiarla, vuol dire più schiacciarla con talmente tanta forza da spappolarla, come usando uno schiacciasassi.

Answer (score 3):

Una delle accezioni di "sdrumare" che riporta il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI18/00388.jpg) è la seguente:

> **2.** Sfregare energicamente. 
>        *Fenoglio*, 5-1-2037: Milton si sdrumò la faccia con le mani. 
>        – Rifl. 
>        *Fenoglio*, 5-1-890: La cagna venne a sdrumarsi contro le gambe di Johnny, così impetuosamente, nell'amoroso im­pulso, che quasi lo ribaltò sulla neve. 
>        – Asportare con lo sfregamento.
>        *Fenoglio*, 4-370: Egli sollevò la faccia e si sdrumò il fan­go dagli angoli.

Quindi, nel contesto del brano citato nella domanda, significa che Milton si sfregò energicamente la faccia con le mani subito dopo aver sentito che l'interlocutore gli chiedeva: «E poi, sai che faccia hai? Di' un po', è molto che non ti specchi?».